# No me funciona el .load en laravel

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

Estoy intentando cargar un archivo `.php` en un div, estoy trabajando con `Laravel` pero el archivo no me carga, ya lo he probado con `php` crudo y si funciona perfectamente. Ya revise rutas y todo esta bien no se que sucede.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.iconStu').click(function() {
    $("#id").load('estudiantes.php');
  });
});
```

Comment: ¿Donde tienes ubicado el archivo ?

Comment: el que quiero cargar, en la carpeta de views

Comment: Cree una ruta y acceda a ella. no directamente al archivo.

Comment: como asi, no te entiendo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Debería** crear una nueva ruta para acceder desde el cliente *(Js)* a las vistas.

En `routes.php` puede tener una ruta, con nombre para acceder desde `JS` , el archivo de la vista debería tener la extensión de `blade`, `estudiantes.blade.php`

```
Route::get('estudiantes',function(){
    return view('estudiantes');
})->name('estudiantes');
```

Sí está haciendo el load desde una vista directamente . podría imprimir la ruta con `route('nombreruta)`

```
$(function() {
  $('.iconStu').click(function() {
    $("#id").load('{{ route('estudiantes') }}');
  });
});
```

O si es desde un archivo externo `JS`

```
$(function() {
  $('.iconStu').click(function() {
    $("#id").load('/estudiantes');
  });
});
```

Comment: gracias , funciona perfectamente